# view file stored in PostgreSQL with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I've stored a pdf file in a postgres database using oid.
Now i need to read it in a browser and download it with php.
I've searching around but found nothing useful.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to read file from database.

To change the content type to other file type check this link:

[Content Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)

```
<?php

   header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); // to pdf: application/pdf
   $database = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=dbname user=username password=userpass");

   $query = pg_query($database,"select * from table where id = 1") or die(pg_last_error());
   $row_query = pg_fetch_assoc($query);

   $image_oid = $row_query['image'];

   pg_query($database, "begin");
   $handle = pg_lo_open($database, $image_oid, "r");
   pg_lo_read_all($handle);
   pg_query($database, "commit");

?>
```